# Trouble clearing an SQLite3 table with PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to use `PHP` to clear an `SQLite3` table (delete it's contents), however I'm having trouble with the code I'm using:

```
<?php
     $connection = new SQLite3('/home/pi/LCP/db_try.db');
     if($connection){
           echo 'connected'
           $connection->query("DELETE FROM Meter1")'
     }
?>
```

I've also tried `DROP TABLE` and `exec` instead of `query` to no avail.

Comment: I've never used SQLite3 but it says for DML statements to use http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.exec.php. From there you can use http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.lasterrormsg.php to get an error. `DROP` and `DELETE` in mysql at least, are much different comments, `drop` will causes errors if you try to use the table again. Maybe `truncate` is available.

Comment: @user3783243 I forgot to add that I had also tried `exec`. I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Did you try it with the error reporting? What is the return of the execution, `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Comment: I just assigned `$connection->exec("DELETE FROM Meter1")` to a variable, echoed it and it was `FALSE`

Comment: @user3783243 I just saw your `lastErrorMsg()` edit and it says I'm `attempting to write a readonly database`, this leads me to believe that my `apache2` user doesn't have the permissions.

Comment: The error message to me indicates the DB is read only, possibly a slave, maybe `home/pi/LCP/db_try.db` has the wrong connection info. I know nothing about `SQLite3` though so maybe the error messages just aren't useful.